# Are geodesic buffers dependant on geographic v projected coordinate system?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, buffer, geodesic

I am trying to create a geodesic buffer in ArcGIS (v10.7) but the outcome differs depending on whether I use a projected coordinate system of geographic coordinate sytem, while I would expect that the output of a geodesic buffer is the same, independent of coordinate systems. Can anyone please explain this difference? And what would be the preferred input for this algorithm then? A projected or geographic coordinate system?

[image]

Comment: The GCS of the PCS is the same as the GCS you're using, right? And you used the geodesic option when using the PCS version?

Comment: @mkennedy In both the cases, the GCS is:

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian:  Greenwich
Angular Unit:  Degree

Yes indeed, I was using the geodesic option when using the PCS version, the planar buffer was much smaller.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know. If you use the measure tool in ArcMap (geodesic option, of course!), which one matches your buffer radius?  How different is the other one?

Comment: It seems that the buffer radius is matched for the buffer calculated from the GCS. The PCS is larger, sometimes with about 100 nautical miles...

Comment: I would go with a geographic coordinate system. When I had a point that was projected in a UTM projection and I tried a 10,000 KM Geodesic projection the result was really bad (the sides were cut off). However when I re-projected the point into a geographic coordinate system (WGS84) and tried a 10,000 KM Geodesic projection the result looks good.